# Can't put text in one line if there are more words

Tags: html, css, bulma

I can't put my text in one single line if there are more words.  Are there any possible ways to put this text in the block and in one single line? I am using the Bulma framework.

```html
<div class="column">
    <h3 class="subtitle classBorder">1-9 Klasė</h3>
    <div class="column firstPlan">
      <span class="euroSign">&euro;</span><h1 class="title pricePlan">8<span class="subtitle workingHours">ak.val.</span></h1>
      <div class="textSection">
      <span class="thisIsDarkGreen"></span>
      <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span><span class="thisIsLightGreen">Ištisas dėmesys stengiantis patobulėti</span><br>
      <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span><span class="thisIsLightGreen">Ištisas dėmesys stengiantis patobulėti</span><br>
      <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span><span class="thisIsLightGreen">Ištisas dėmesys stengiantis patobulėti</span><br>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `<br>` tags?